# Unwrapping with equal distance between islands

Tags: uv

When i unwrap an object the distance between between the islands seems to be based off the size of the island. That means that smaller islands still lie relatively close to each other, compared to the large islands, causing artifacts when painting in substance painter.

Isn't it possible to make islands have a constant distance to other islands regardsless of size.

Comment: If mesh has rectangular islands the distance between them should be that one which was used while unwrapping (options right after unwrap). More complex shapes like organic models will be placed on UV map based on pack opportunities of unwrapping method and amount of seams; distance between islands isn't based on proportions in islands sizes